# What Is The Correct Syntax for Excel VBA If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first VBA code. I'll simply paste what I want to do in code. It's easy to understand:

```
Sub SetRangeColorIndex()

If Range("y4:y6").Interior.ColorIndex = 0 And Range("y4:y6").Value = "" Then
     Range("y4:y6").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
End If

End Sub
```

Everything works fine separately, but not when put in an If Statement. I tried different spacing but it didn't work. I get "Run-time error '13': type mismatch" in a message box.

What's the problem here?

Comment: You have to loop and check each cell individually.

Comment: `Range("y4:y6").Value` returns a variant array, you cannot compare it to a String.

Comment: ^ Which means that the *Everything works fine separately, but not when put in an If Statement* cannot be true.

Comment: Thanks guys!

I appreciate your help. Would you elaborate more on the correct syntax? If possible, I would like the following:

1- an example of executing the procedure by looping.
2- another possible way of executing the same result.

Best regards,

Alex